# Mostar los numeros divisores de un numero

Tags: javascript

El enunciado es este:

> Muestre todos los numeros divisores de un numero introducido x pantalla

Y a mi se me ocurrio hacerlo de esta manera, cual es el problema aca? Ni siquiera entra al for.

```
var numero;

numero = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un numero",0));

for(var i = numero;i <= 1;i--){
    if(numero % i == 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Luego lo termine resolviendo de esta manera

```
var numero;

numero = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un numero",0));

for(var i = 1;i <= numero;i++){
    if(numero % i == 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La segunda respuesta parece estar bien. En la primera respuesta no entra al ciclo `for` porque tu condición de paro está mal.

Por ejemplo, si pones 10, en la primera vuelta `i` vale 10, y puesto que 10 no es menor o igual a 1, no entrará al ciclo. Por lo que debes modificar la condición de este modo:

```javascript
// const numero = 10;
const numero = parseInt(prompt('Introduce un numero',0));

for(let i = numero; i >= 0; i--){
    if(numero % i === 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
}

for(let i = 0; i <= numero; i++){
    if(numero % i === 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```